# Moodle Authentication

Tags: authentication, moodle

I have logged into a website by writting the below code in file `xyz.php`. When I run this file I get logged into the moodle website. Is there any way to logout similarly to the below login code?

```
$user = authenticate_user_login($username, $password);
complete_user_login($user);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the file https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/login/logout.php you will see a call to the function require_logout()

This should ensure the user is logged out.